# TcpClient close works differently in .NET Core and .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a class library that I use for making TCP socket connections.  Here is the relevant code converted to a console application:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task receiveTask;

            using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                // Make a connection
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("172.25.106.60", 5334).ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Start the receive task
                receiveTask = RunReceiveTask(tcpClient);

                // Let the connection sit for a bit before disconnecting
                await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            // Wait until the receive task has ended
            await receiveTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async Task RunReceiveTask(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            // This loop continues until the socket reader returns null, which means the socket has been closed,
            // either by this application closing it or by the remote disconnecting.
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[65535];
            int bytesRead;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    bytesRead = await tcpClient.GetStream().ReadAsync(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);

                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        // This is where we would process the data received.

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // This means the remote end closed the connection
                        Console.WriteLine("Socket closed by remote");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Socket closed by this end");
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Some other exception, for example an unexpected drop in the connection
                    Console.WriteLine($"Socket error: {ex.Message}");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code establishes a socket connection to a listening device, waits 3 seconds, and then closes the connection.  For the purpose of this test, it doesn't need to send or receive any actual data.

If I create a .Net Framework application with the above code, `TCPClient` throws an `ObjectDisposedException` so the console displays "Socket closed by this end", which is the desired behavior and what has always worked for me in the past.

If I put the same code in a .Net Core console application, `TCPClient` throws an `IOException`, so the console displays "Socket error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."

This surprises me because the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync?view=net-6.0) seems to indicate that `ObjectDisposedException` is still to be expected when the stream closes.  I could just catch `IOException` as well, but both sockets that were cleanly closed and those that closed with an error seem to throw that same exception.  The linked documentation says I can check the `ErrorCode` property of the `InnerException` of the `ObjectDisposedException`, so I suppose I could make that work.

I guess my question then is did something change in the .Net Core version of System.Net.Sockets, or am I doing something wrong on my side?  It seems odd that the documentation would list an `ObjectDisposedException` when apparently it can't ever be thrown.  And if this is expected behavior, is what I listed above the correct way to detect the difference between closures and socket errors?

Comment: Socket shutdown by your end shouldn't be an unexpected event - so why can you not arrange for `RunReceiveTask` to receive and make use of a `CancellationToken` which should let things be aborted cleanly and you not have to reason about exception types at all?

Comment: Even if I flag the `CancellationToken` that I pass to `NetworkStream.ReadAsync` method, it doesn't actually cancel the returned task (at least it didn't used to, it's possible it does now).  So my existing class library doesn't have a `CancellationToken` parameter because it would just be ignored anyway.  I could add one, but it would be a breaking change.  Clients of my library currently know they should close the socket and that will end the receive task.

Comment: Maybe wrap the stream and use your own `CancellationToken`?